# Removing comments using lex: why doesn't this work?

Tags: python, lex, ply

I'm writing a parser using Python/lex and trying to create an entry to remove C-style comments. My current (faulty) attempt is:

```
def t_comment_ignore(t): 
    r'(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(//[^\n]*)'
    pass
```

This produced a quirk that baffled me. When I parse the string below:

```
input = """
if // else mystery  
=/*=*/= 
true /* false 
*/ return"""
```

The output tokens are:

```
['IF', 'EQUAL', 'TIMES', 'EQUAL', 'DIVIDE', 'EQUAL', 'TRUE', 'RETURN']
```

Apparently the comment on line 3 wasn't recognized properly and 3 of the symbols therein were returned as tokens.

But if I add a space before the comment in line 3, i.e.:

```
input = """
if // else mystery  
= /*=*/= 
true /* false 
*/ return"""
```

I get:

```
['IF', 'EQUAL', 'EQUAL', 'TRUE', 'RETURN']
```

Debugging showed that all 3 comments were recognized correctly when the extra space was added.

Well, I'm utterly baffled by this behavior. Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,
 Paulo

PS: As some probably noticed, this enchilada is from Problem Set 2 in https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs262. They give a more elaborate solution using another of lex's features, but I'm wondering if my approach is sound and if my code is fixable.

Comment: Your `t_comment_ignore` function doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: How does your implementation handle a `*` within a `/*  */` comment?  Also how does it handle something like `/* comment // comment */ return`?

Comment: The 1st case wasn't handled correctly--the middle asterisk "shoots down" the [^*] in the regex, but the 2nd worked OK--the [^*] "chomps" the double slashes. I've changed the regex to `(\/\*.*\*\/)|(//[^\n]*)` and `/*  *    */`is handled OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your pattern for EQUALS matches `=.` instead of (or as well as) `=`.

By the way, the correct comment pattern is `/[*][^*]*[*]+([^/*][^*]*[*]+)*/|//[^\n]*`.

Comment: Ippon! Actually the bug was in my EQUALEQUAL pattern (I'd prefer not to post my heroically dumb '==' oeuvre). Your regex also makes an awful lot more sense than mine. Thanks alot!